# Using QAbstractItemModel as a Q_PROPERTY inside c++ with READ WRITE

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying to achieve a filter model that has a source model inside QML. Both of my models are c++ based and registered as modules.

Assuming I have:

```
ListView {
    id: autocomplete
    anchors.top: field.bottom
    model: MyTreeModelCompleter {
        separator: "."
        model: MyTreeModel{}

    }
}
```

The c++ of MyTreeModelCompleter:

```
class TreeModelCompleter : public QCompleter
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString separator READ separator WRITE setSeparator)
    Q_PROPERTY(QAbstractItemModel* model READ model WRITE setModel)

public:
    explicit TreeModelCompleter(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    explicit TreeModelCompleter(QAbstractItemModel *model, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    QString separator() const;
    QAbstractItemModel* model();
public slots:
    void setSeparator(const QString&);
    void setModel(QAbstractItemModel*);

protected:
    QStringList splitPath(const QString &path) const override;
    QString pathFromIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const override;

private:
    QString m_sep;
    QAbstractItemModel *m_model;
};
```

MyTreeModel c++:

```
class MyTreeModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
};
```

MyTreeModel QML:

```
MyTreeElement {
    property bool check
    property string name: "name1"
    property string description: "desc of name1"

    MyTreeElement {
        property bool check
        property string name: "name2"
        property string description: "desc of name2"
    }
    MyTreeElement {
        property bool check
        property string name: "name3"
        property string description: "desc of name3"

        MyTreeElement {
            property bool check
            property string name: "name 4"
            property string description: "desc of name4"

            MyTreeElement {
                property bool check
                property string name: "name 5"
                property string description: "desc of name5"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

MyTreeelement:

```
class MyTreeNode : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<MyTreeNode> nodes READ nodes)
    Q_CLASSINFO("DefaultProperty", "nodes")
    MyTreeNode(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    void setParentNode(MyTreeNode *parent);
    Q_INVOKABLE MyTreeNode *parentNode() const;
    bool insertNode(MyTreeNode *node, int pos = (-1));
    QQmlListProperty<MyTreeNode> nodes();

    MyTreeNode *childNode(int index) const;
    void clear();

    Q_INVOKABLE int pos() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE int count() const;

private:
    QList<MyTreeNode *> m_nodes;
    MyTreeNode *m_parentNode;
};
```

My main issue is including `MyTreeModel` inside the completer model `MyTreeModelCompleter`. The issue is generated when I try to bind them, the compiler complains that the values don't match in types as 1 is `QAbstractItemModel*` and the other is `QAbstractItemModel`.
Is there a way to get this model binding to work?
This is by no means a working code, because I think the issue is in the embedding of the Models in one another and not in the actual code.

The error:

> Cannot assign object of type "MyTreeModel" to property of type
>   "QAbstractItemModel*" as the former is neither the same as the latter
>   nor a sub-class of it.

Comment: my bad, i changed the code and forgot to edit

Comment: mytreeelement is another c++ class registered under MyTreeElement in QML

Comment: I was still editing to reflect changes to code

Comment: You could upload your project to github to analyze it, you will understand that your project is a bit extensive and there are many hidden things.

Comment: I'm happy to be referred to some explanation about how to include a model inside another model where both are originally c++ and registered inside main to be exposed to QML

Comment: I am afraid that I can not indicate anything since I can not analyze its code correctly, until what I see seems coherent so maybe the error is elsewhere. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A way to handle the problem is to use `QObject *` instead of `QAbstractItemModel *` for the `model` property. Here is an example :

```
    class TreeModelCompleter : public QCompleter
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PROPERTY(QString separator READ separator WRITE setSeparator)
        Q_PROPERTY(QObject* model READ model WRITE setModel)

    public:
        explicit TreeModelCompleter(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
        explicit TreeModelCompleter(QAbstractItemModel *model, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

        QString separator() const;
        QObject* model();
    public slots:
        void setSeparator(const QString&);
        void setModel(QObject*); 

    protected:
        QStringList splitPath(const QString &path) const override;
        QString pathFromIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const override;

    private:
        QString m_sep;
        QAbstractItemModel *m_model;
    };
```